# Python how to create rank based on multiple variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

What I'm trying to do is create a rank for children by age under their parent's ID:

| ID | Relationship | Age | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | Parent | 52 | 0 |
| 101 | Spouse | 50 | 0 |
| 101 | Child | 15 | 1 |
| 101 | Child | 12 | 2 |
| 201 | Parent | 40 | 0 |
| 201 | Child | 10 | 1 |

I got as far as:
`df =df.sort_values(['ID','Relationship','Age'])`
but don't know where to go from there.

Comment: Is this pandas? Then you should tag that...

Comment: Within groups, if child, assign your ranks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df["Rank"] = df[df["Relationship"]=="Child"].groupby("ID")["Age"].rank("dense", ascending=False).reindex(df.index).fillna(0)
>>> df
    ID Relationship  Age  Rank
0  101       Parent   52   0.0
1  101       Spouse   50   0.0
2  101        Child   15   1.0
3  101        Child   12   2.0
4  201       Parent   40   0.0
5  201        Child   10   1.0
```

You are first selecting rows where Relationship is Child, grouping all the children by "ID", ranking them, assigning it back to the original `df` and filling `np.nan` with 0.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Using `where` and `na_option='top'` will save the `reindex` and `fillna`:  as in `df.where(df.Relationship == 'Child').groupby(df.ID).Age.rank('dense', ascending=False, na_option='top') - 1`

Comment: Ah, but for the sample that OP provided, my code is much faster (1.17 ms ± 12.6 µs) vs. yours (2.43 ms ± 27.4 µs)